# How do I address DatePickerFlyout from Code Behind

Tags: c#, visual-studio, xaml, win-universal-app

I want to add an event to a DatePickerFlyout inside my DatePicker to catch the closing and save the value set in the Picker, so I don't need to use the Picker-Button.

This is what i tried:

```
<DatePicker x:Name="customDatePicker" Style="{StaticResource DatePickerStyle2}" MonthFormat="{}{month.abbreviated(3)}" >
    <FlyoutBase.AttachedFlyout>
        <DatePickerFlyout x:Name="customDatePickerFlyout" DatePicked="customDatePickerFlyout_DatePicked" Closed="customDatePickerFlyout_Closed"/>
    </FlyoutBase.AttachedFlyout>
</DatePicker>
```

But it seems this DatePickerFlyout 'customDatePickerFlyout' is not the desired which is called from within  the DatePicker.

[image: my customDatePickerFlyout]

Another approach I tried was this:

```
this.customDatePicker.FlyoutBase.DatePickerFlyout.RegisterPropertyChangedCallback(DatePickerFlyout.OpenedProperty, (d, e) =>
{
    if (!this.customDatePicker.FlyoutBase.DatePickerFlyout.Opened)
    {
        //do something
    }
});
```

as seen from this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33739748/uwp-winrt-detect-when-a-popup-is-about-to-be-closed) which totaly failes in any case.

Comment: There is already a `DatePickerFlyout` attached to the `DatePicker` control, and if you select a date and click the confirm button on the `DatePickerFlyout`, the selected date will be shown on the `DatePicker`, and if you click the cancel button or the region outside of the `DatePickerFlyout`, the date selected date won't be shown on the `DatePicker`. What you mean by "Picker-Button"? You want the `DatePicker` always show the selected date when the `DatePickerFlyout` is closed, and no cancel event should be triggered?

Comment: Correct, this is exactly what I need, what I was trying to do is replacing the button-based save-mechanism by a custom LostFocus-event added to the Flyout or the DatePickerFlyoutPresenter Grid by the name of 'ContentPanel', but I can't find a way to do this, since UWP does not support 'EventSetter'

Comment: A workaround method is you can design a `UserControl` which can show the date and show the `DatePickerFlyout` by tapping. For example a `Grid` with several `TextBlock`.

Comment: So you say it's impossible to bind an event to the customized datepickerflyoutpresenter-style?

Comment: I checked the template style of a `DatePicker`, and just my opinion, when click the "FlyoutButton", it shows the `DatePickerFlyout` from the code behind, which I don't have a access to it. Yes it's also possible to solve this problem by modifying the style, but you will need to remove this button from the template, and this method has no difference with designing a `UserControl` to me. If you want this method, I can wrote it as an answer, but it's not the problem about binding an event to the customized style, it's just we don't have access to the original one. Sorry if this is not helpful.

Comment: Oh it is helpfull. Now I know it's more usefull to use a workaround. Thank you.